# Elasticsearch my existing index is deleted

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a self-hosted elasticsearch in my server. I have integrated with my code after certain days my existing data is deleted. Only If I create a new entry this will store in the index

I have used Amazon aws free tier server. I have used rabbitmq in this server also. I know the more ram needed for the elastic search but I need to know the reason for the data loss

THis is my server log [link](https://shrib.com/#0M3z5r3Hg-C.TlgW2k4E)

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch never deletes an index. It means that you probably have something, someone running a DELETE index query from somewhere.

If you look at your logs you should see something like this.

Data is stored on disk in the `data` dir.

Comment: I am managing the server I can't run the delete index query
will check the index

Comment: I am having 1GB ram Can It be a issue

Comment: Will check the logs. Can you please let me know the log directory?

Comment: This is the log I have get in my server [link](https://shrib.com/#0M3z5r3Hg-C.TlgW2k4E)

Comment: Is your cluster exposed publicly on internet? Sounds like someone is trying to hack it judging by the logs

Comment: yeah my cluster is exposed publically

Comment: DON'T EVER DO THAT! Or use xpack (commercial plugin) to secure it.

Comment: I have now changed to access only via server

Comment: Check the logs again to make sure no one has access to it anymore. But your server might have been compromised though if an hacker succeeded to run one process at some point. If you are using 6.2.3 that should reduce the risk. Please give a try to cloud.elastic.co as well if you want to use a secured service OOTB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168838/discussion-between-tharunkumar-and-dadoonet).

Comment: So In future this issue will not come right?
If I secure the elasticsearch become not accesible in public

Answer (score 2):

You have been attacked by a bot. If that happens again, try to list indices by GET /_cat/indices. If you see something like 'meow' or 'warn' there, then it is known bot attackers.

I faced same issue and did some investigations. Port 9200 was open on my server! Despite of iptables rules which restrict everything except 443, 8443 and 22. And the cause was docker! It added one more rule after all mine.

```
sudo iptables -S | grep 9200

-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.2/32 ! -i br-cab97908df43 -o br-cab97908df43 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
```

How is that possible? Why docker does this crazy thing? The reason is default docker-compose.yml which I took from elasticsearch website.

Change

```
 ports:
 - 9200:9200
```

to

```
ports:
- 127.0.0.1:9200:9200
```

Comment: I found the xyz-meow indices created in my elasticsearch, but I did not have a docker installed on that server. The strange thing is, even the ports are not open, only to my static ip it is open. Changing ports for now and deleting the indices, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me once, I was working on some queries when all my indices got suddenly deleted.

I had in mind securing the whole thing but I kept on postponing it. It just took an hour to install x-pack and figure out all the errors that may arrive because of that, but no suddenly deleted indices ever since :D.